# sscanf to stringstream conversion

Tags: c++, istringstream

```
 if (1 != sscanf(line, "%s", name)) continue;
```

Earlier in the code we have

```
char line[128];

char name[128];
```

What's another way of writing this line using istringstream instead of sscanf?

Comment: Agreed. Not gonna post an answer on this..

Comment: Give him a break. He has only been here 28 days. I often don't accept answers until at least a month has passed.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::istringstream stream( line );
if( !( stream >> name ) )
    continue;
```